# Extended Euclidean algorithm convention [In C]

Tags: c, greatest-common-divisor

I was looking for a `Extended Euclidean` algorithm in `C`. I found the following piece of code:

```
int gcdExtended(int a, int b, int *x, int *y) 
{ 
    if (a == 0) 
    { 
        *x = 0; 
        *y = 1; 
        return b; 
    } 
    int x1, y1;
    int gcd = gcdExtended(b%a, a, &x1, &y1); 
    *x = y1 - (b/a) * x1; 
    *y = x1;
    return gcd; 
}
```

so for `gcdExtended(0,0)` it will return: `x=0` and `y=1`. But I saw some other versions of the algorithem which return `x=0` and `y=0`. Both mathematically are true. But, is there a convention for this issue?

Comment: What issue? If both are correct, there is no issue..

Comment: @EugeneSh. i'm afraid that the diff can be different when testing and it will failed. Only asking if there is a convention.

Comment: Ah, convention.. It says "conversion" in the title.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, my bad. (changed it)

Comment: Generally, the goal of the extended Euclidean algorithm is to find the multiplicative inverse of one input modulo the other. That is, it is desired to find `x` and `y` such that `a*x` is 1 modulo `b` and `b*y` is 1 modulo `a`. In this case, the input 0 and 0 for `a` and `b` is out of the domain of the algorithm, and there is no point in defining it. No values of `x` and `y` can satisfy `0*x` is 1 modulo `0` and `0*y` is 1 modulo `0`. The user should never call the function with these values.

Comment: The point is that there is actually no "mathematically true" result. This isn't really a standard enough function that there's a convention for how to report erroneous input.